# How to read locators from a json file in protractor?

Tags: protractor

I want to develop a framework where i keep all the locators at one place, in a json file say test.json. like this.

```
{
    "yourName": "by.model('yourName')"
}
```

And I want to read this in specs as below.

```
    var test = require('./test.json');

describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
  it('should add a todo', function() {
    browser.get('https://angularjs.org');

    var webElement = element(testtest.yourName);

    webElement.sendKeys('write first protractor test');
  });
});
```

but when i do this getting error as **Failed: Invalid locator** with following error trace.

```
Failures:
1) angularjs homepage todo list should add a todo
  Message:
    Failed: Invalid locator
  Stack:
    TypeError: Invalid locator
        at Object.check [as checkedLocator] (C:\Users\karunakaralchala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\by.js:267:9)
        at WebDriver.findElements (C:\Users\karunakaralchala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:919:18)
        at C:\Users\karunakaralchala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:159:44
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\karunakaralchala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1379:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\karunakaralchala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\karunakaralchala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)
        at asyncRun (C:\Users\karunakaralchala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2775:27)
        at C:\Users\karunakaralchala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:639:7
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)Error
        at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (C:\Users\karunakaralchala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:396:27)
        at ElementArrayFinder._this.(anonymous function) [as sendKeys] (C:\Users\karunakaralchala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:99:30)
        at ElementFinder.(anonymous function) [as sendKeys] (C:\Users\karunakaralchala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:730:22)
        at Object.<anonymous> (E:\ui\TestTest\todo-spec.js:9:20)
        at C:\Users\karunakaralchala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:94:23
        at new ManagedPromise (C:\Users\karunakaralchala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1082:7)
        at controlFlowExecute (C:\Users\karunakaralchala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:80:18)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\karunakaralchala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\karunakaralchala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)
        at asyncRun (C:\Users\karunakaralchala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2820:25)
    From: Task: Run it("should add a todo") in control flow
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\karunakaralchala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:79:14)
    From asynchronous test:
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (E:\ui\TestTest\todo-spec.js:4:7)
        at Object.<anonymous> (E:\ui\TestTest\todo-spec.js:3:5)
        at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
```

Is there any better way to do this? or what should i need to make it work?

Comment: Why not use the page object format instead of JSON?  http://www.protractortest.org/#/page-objects

Comment: thanks for your comment, I tried the same, but i want to achieve the above for better maintenance of my code, where i would keep all the locator at one place

Comment: Ok... the Protractor guide suggests you to use Page Objects but it's your code.  Keeping everything in one file will eventually become massive, making it very difficult to navigate and debug.

Comment: Can you check if the below solution of using 'eval' worked?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the direct answer to the question, but I think you are not attempting the problem in a traditional way and sort of partially reinventing the wheel.

Instead of keeping locators in a separate JSON structure, organize them into [Page Objects](http://www.protractortest.org/#/page-objects) - separate page objects (including element locators and methods to interact with a page) for separate pages or parts of pages.

Comment: My intention is rather than writing setter and getter functions for every field(I have more than 100 fields in page), I want to achieve this.I_Enter_Text = function(locator, expectedText) {  
  var webElement = element(locator);
  webElement.sendKeys(expectedText);
 };

Comment: Alecxe...why not combine both approaches together and have a page object which will have its own small json to load object definitions to keep it loosely coupled.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

**test.json**

```
{
  "siteURL": "https://angularjs.org",
  "locators": {
    "todoText": {
      "model": "todoList.todoText"
    }
  }
}
```

**spec.js**

```
    var test = require('./test.json');

   describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
      it('should add a todo', function() {
        browser.get(test.siteURL);

        var webElement = element(by.model(test.locators.todoText.model));

        webElement.sendKeys('write first protractor test');
  });
});
```

One complete example using BDD Cucumber, json and pageobject model here. https://github.com/aluzardo/protractor-cucumber-tests/

Answer (score 0):

One simple mistake in your approach.

The values from JSON are read as string and you are passing a string to `element()` and not a locator(not a `by` object)

```
var webElement = element(test.yourName); // Incorrect. test.yourName returns  string
```

Change it way and voila ! You should be good. Use eval(). Refer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)

```
    var webElement = element(eval(test.yourName));
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working, Now I'm going with slightly different approach